# Clear textField immediately after entering char in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, documentlistener

After entering into textField one of this letters: "e,E,f,F,g,G", the comboBox in my app is changing. I want to clear my textField immediately after entering one of this letters but i can't do this. I use :

```
tekstField.setText("");
```

but it doesn't work. Probably it because that i can't eat listener in Swing.

```
   textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    updateLog(e);
                }

                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                }

                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    updateLog(e);
                }

                public void updateLog(DocumentEvent e) {
                    Document doc = (Document) e.getDocument();
                    int docLength = doc.getLength();
                    String key;
                    try {
                        key = e.getDocument().getText(0, docLength);
                        if (docLength == 1 && !key.matches("^[0-9]$")) {
                            char labSymbol = key.charAt(0);
                            switch (labSymbol) {
                                case 'E' :
                                case 'e' :
                                    labTypeComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
                                    break;
                                case 'F' :
                                case 'f' :
                                    labTypeComboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
                                    break;
                                case 'G' :
                                case 'g' :
                                    labTypeComboBox.setSelectedIndex(2);
                                    break;
                                default :
                                    break;
                            }
                            tekstField.setText("");
                        }
                    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });
```

Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share the complete program

Comment: No i can't because it's a bigger project. I'll try to explain it if something is misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you try tekstField.setText(null);

Comment: Why would you use a JTextField to select an item in a combo box? Would the user not get confused/frustrated when they type a character into the text field and it disappears right away?

Comment: Because it's quicker than select item in comboBox. It works but the letter from JTextField don't disappear as i want and this is a problem.

Comment: A combo box already supports selection of an item by using a keyboard based on the first character of the item in the combo box.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I want to do it with JTextField and i wonder if it is possible.